# How to speed up the MySQL query needed for pagination - million records in the table

Tags: php, mysql

There is about 1 milion records.
Query is needed for the pagination system.

Query looks like this:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table 
WHERE field4 = '$value' 
ORDER BY field5 ASC limit $offset, 30;
```

There is index on field4 and field5.

All fields are varchar type.
Field5 was tested as int but no real improvement notice.

Right now query with `limit 0, 30` takes about 1 second, but query with `limit 119970, 30` takes about 20 seconds.

Is this realistic to obtain result less than 0.1 second on paginated pages? Such loading time is needed for the website to offer good user experience.

EXPLAIN (select with `limit 0,30`)

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: table
type: index
possible_keys: NULL
key: field5
key_len: 768
ref: NULL
rows: 223636
Extra: Using where
```

Comment: How often does `$value` change? Can you cache the results of the query? Do you really expect users to get to the 120,000th result?

Comment: Show the table schema and explain for query.

Comment: @Mark Elliot value change many times there are about 2000 different values. There are many similar queries, so MySQL cache is limited and woul like to have the first load also fast. Yes, I expect users could paginate as there is even link to last pagination page, bots will scan all webiste. Now even first page load 5 sec.

Comment: Have you optimized your server config at all? I mean, I wouldn't expect this query to scream, but a time of < 1 second should be easily acheiveable on reasonable hardware.

Comment: @Tyler Eaves MySQL server is quite optimized, using my-huge.cnf. What type of hardware do you have on mind? I am using machine with 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo and 2 GB of SDRAM.

Comment: you need to try SQL queries cache in MySQL. it's help to optimize the perfromance

Comment: @jQuery On Planet MySQL But query must be fast at first time also. Cache is not solving this problem. BTW what cache combination will you suggest?

Comment: You might be looking at a hardware limitation rather than a software one.  Depending on how many people are hitting your server, you need to be looking at a lot more than 2GB of SDRAM.

Comment: @afuzzyllama There is planty of free space in SDRAM now, and I am using it for testing right now on development server.

Comment: @zerkms I edited the post and added the explain information. Table schama is very simple as I wrote all fields are varchar(64);

Answer (score 2):

You could try table partitioning:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much your data is changing, you could use [memcached](http://memcached.org/) to reduce the amount of times a certain query needs to get run and reduce the response time for most users.

Comment: You might also analyze usage to see which pages are actually loaded.  Maybe only the first 100 are being looked at.  Cache those pages, don't bother with the rest.  (Of course, pages beyond the first two or three might not be viewed now because of performance.)

Comment: All pages must load fast as bots will scan all website (it's all crawlable), and loading time is important factor now.

Comment: If your data and pagination stays relatively static, I would suggest setting up memcached.  It really improves performance with sties that use repetitive queries.

Comment: Will memcached serve the result fast at first time or need to run once to cache the page first? I need the solution, which will speed up the loading time at first time.

Comment: memcached will not speed up the query the first time (and every subsequent time the query needs to be run).

Comment: Unfortunatelly I must avoid this kind of solution as first time loading time matters.

Answer (score 1):

It should have index "B-TREE (field4, field5)".
This index will allow MySQL to use field4 to find the records and limit them with order on field5.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion that the data should not be fully loaded into pagination directly instead using ajax query again for different page when user click it. So in exact page it only shows the current page number data. Hope it helps and Good Luck.

Comment: Ajax can't be used as then paginated pages won't be crawlable by search engine bots.

Comment: That doesn't help any at all. That would result in EXACTLY the query OP posted.

Comment: @Newbie1: I know I am late for this post, but I personally DO agree with Eric T on this. Loading the pagination with ajax is actually a common practice for many sites. Search Engine Bots can still crawl the sites, as you only need to provide an ?page=... for your Urls. However, the site will be loaded quicker and till the user scrolls down to the bottom, you can load the pagination, so the users will not notice anything at all...

Answer (score 0):

Is this table have PK?
`Select field1,field2,field3 from table as a 
join (select PK from table WHERE field4 = '$value' 
ORDER BY field5 ASC limit $offset, 30) as b
on a.PK=b.PK;`

Comment: Yes, id is Primary Key, your query proposition didn't speed up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making another table (table 6) that is an indexed hash of table4? Searching numbers instead of text is going to be a lot faster so the query is something like:

SELECT field1, field2, field3 Force Index(Table6) FROM table 
WHERE field 6 = '$hashvalue' AND field4 = '$value' 
ORDER BY field5 ASC limit $offset, 30;

It should help to eliminate 99.99% of data before it has to text search and should speed up your queries regardless of the offset....

Comment: Could you please explain it more (table (table 6) that is an indexed hash of table4). What is field 6 and '$hashvalue'?